# How to integrate groups with AbstractBaseUser in django?

Tags: django, django-models

How can I add group capabilities to my custom django user model? I seen that I'm able to inherit the PermissionsMixin but I do not see any group functionality in doing so. Basically, I need to be able to add custom groups to the custom user model.

Comment: Just inherit PermissionsMixin and create your custom group `user.grooups.add(Group.objects.create(name='mycustomgroup')`. Or you want something else?

Comment: PermissionsMixin - is an abstract model, it has groups field, which is ManyToMany field to auth.Group model (read the docs about it). To create custom group - you call `group = Group.objects.create(name='mycustomgroup')`. Also you can assign permissions to group: `group.permissions.add(Persmission.objects.get(codename='myapp.add_mymodel')` To assign group to user you use this `user.groups.add(group)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your custom django user model inherit from AbstractUser,
by default it already inherits the PermissionsMixin

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    Username, password and email are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
    ...
```

So, u can use the default groups options.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.groups)